# Monitor bluetooth peripheral state changes even when the app is killed

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

At the moment I am using `CBCentralManager`'s constructor that accepts its delegate and other params. From that point on if the app is in foreground or background state the delegate method is called as expected as soon as the bluetooth state changes (such as turnOn/turnOff). When the app is not running even in background i.e when the app is killed, the app is not launched and the delegate method is never called by the system.

I've made sure that i have `bluetooth-central` and `bluetooth-peripheral` under `UIBackgroundModes` in the `Info.plist`.

So is there any way to receive the state change notifications even when the app is not running at all?

**Sidenote**: Our app relies on bluetooth to function properly so it is important to keep the bluetooth turned on. Idea is if a user turns off the bluetooth we need to alert them via local notification that it needs to be turned on for our app function properly.

Comment: If the user kills your app then there isn't anything you can do

Answer (score 2):

> So is there any way to receive the state change notifications even when the app is not running at all?

***Unfortunately , there is no way to receive the state change notifications even when the app is not running at all.***

**Note:** Even with *iBeacons*, you need to wake up the app before you can start listening to changes in Bluetooth device status.
 An *iBeacon* can wake up your app into the background using monitoring APIs.  It can do this even if your app has not been launched since device reboot, or even if the app has been killed from the task switcher (although the latter requires iOS 7.1+)  This works by your app calling the `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` method on `CLLocationManager`, and also implementing the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol's `locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:`,  `locationManager:didEnterRegion:` and/or `locationManager:didExitRegion:` methods.